# Detection of long images fails

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, face-recognition

I trained a few images and label the live image with the trained data. But when the live image is little far away from the camera my algorithm couldn't detect those images. Is there any way to even detect far images ?

Things I tried :

(*) Trained more images (i.e) increased dataset

(*) Used Image filter - Like medium filter, Gaussian filter

But those things too failed in detecting far images.

**The detector couldn't detect images that are 5-6th far from the camera.**

Comment: Please show us some samples

Comment: Please consider things like the Hough transform.  There's no training for that.  You can play with the parameters to make it accept more lines but you might also get more false positives.

Comment: @MH304 it isn't about the sample code. In fact you can take any face detecting code and try. You won't able to detect images that are far from the live camera.

Comment: @SuhasC Will try that

Comment: I meant sample images! Besides in interpreting an image's feature, the size of the neighborhoods have a great effect on the results. For example if you are looking for circles you have to define a specific interval for the radius, and with moving the object, these circles may get too small to fit in that interval, so it truly depends on the algorithm you use and they're not supposed to work for all images.